# Socket & SendMail - How to combine correctly?

Tags: c#, sockets, sendmail, chilkat

Who can help me to combine these two sources codes.

1. http://pastebin.com/zvaxzPsc - Socket Class Working with RFC1928 rules
2. http://pastebin.com/TN27RijR - Chilkat Send Mail

I want to make that Chilkat Send Mail [ `public void SendMail(string toList, string from, string bccList, string subject, string body, string pass)` ] to send through the Socket Class from first source code.

How to do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can't unless Chilkat has a constructor which takes a regular socket.

I suggest that you check the API documentation for Chilkat to see how to configure it to use a proxy.

Comment: I tried it ... have a communication with socket, but does not use communication method described in RFC1928 rules.

Comment: then you need to contact chilkat support. The question is too localized for stackoverflow.